# Is there a way to save the results of LINQPad.Util.Compile and rerun it over long periods of time

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I've got a scripting web service that will download and run linqpad .linq programs from a content management system.  I'm currently doing things like the below code.  Is there a way to save the results of LINQPad.Util.Compile and store it somewhere, so that I could use it untill the .linq file has changed?  Right now I think it's compiling again every time, and produces many compilation folders.

```
public static object DownloadAndRunScript(string scriptFilePath, object args)
{
     var compiledScript = LINQPad.Util.Compile(scriptFilePath, true);
     var queryExecutorResult = compiledScript.Run(LINQPad.QueryResultFormat.Text, args);
     return (object)queryExecutorResult.ReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using LINQPad 5+? It uses Roslyn for compilation, which is entirely in-memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a caching function for this fairly easily. Something like this:

```
static Dictionary<string, Tuple<DateTime, QueryCompilation>> _cache
    = new Dictionary<string, System.Tuple<System.DateTime, QueryCompilation>>();

public static QueryCompilation GetCompilation (string scriptFilePath)
{
    Tuple<DateTime, LINQPad.ObjectModel.QueryCompilation> entry;
    var writeTime = new FileInfo (scriptFilePath).LastWriteTimeUtc;

    lock (_cache)
        if (_cache.TryGetValue (scriptFilePath, out entry) && entry.Item1 == writeTime)
            return entry.Item2;

    var compiledScript = LINQPad.Util.Compile (scriptFilePath, true);

    lock (_cache)
        _cache [scriptFilePath] = Tuple.Create (writeTime, compiledScript);

    return compiledScript;
}
```